# Using enum values in switch case statement

Tags: webforms

I am using `enum` keyword to define set of values which I read from database tables.

I am not confident that these values will remain constant in the database and in `switch` `case` statement we need to give constant values. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If the values are not supposed to be constant they should reside in a database table and you should use a join to retrieve the actual value.

Answer (score 0):

I would use some kind of unique identifier for the database row.  Not the identity field or the smart key but rather some type of abstract value or abbreviation.  Then just reference that abstract value in the case statement instead of the value that will change.

Answer (score 0):

If your application its the main access point to the database, or if you have others application that shared the same data access logic, you can use the enum values as contants in the switch statement, and store in the database the int values of the enum. So, when you retrieve the values from the db, you parsed them to get the enum value.